# Git Diff OutPut in PHP Array

Tags: php, bash

Having an issue getting a gitt diff output to be stored as an array in PHP.

```
$modifiedFiles = `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR HEAD -- '*.php'`;

var_dump($modifiedFiles);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 """
    app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php\n
    app/Http/Controllers/LawyerController.php\n
    """
```

I then tried:

```
$modifiedFiles = explode('\n', $modifiedFiles);

var_dump();
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(82) "app/Http/Controllers/SomeFile.php
app/Http/Controllers/OtherFile.php
"
}
```

I just want the output to be a PHP array of files. Any tips?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php Second parameter is the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here:

```
explode('/n', $modifiedFiles);
```

This line needs to be

```
explode("\n", $modifiedFiles);
```

Only double-quoted strings will interpret newlines and similar escape sequences, etc. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

You also have a forward-slash instead of a back-slash.

Comment: Sorry I had pasted it wrong. I actually realized that and did '\n' but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you mean you tried `'\n'` or `"\n"`? The double quotes are the important part.

Comment: that was it!      It was single quotes. Bah what a noob mistake. Thanks man!